# I am getting TypeError saying forEach is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display Linechart using chartist.js. I have used `reduce()` to extract data from `props`. I have keys as `year` and values as `average value` in averages object. But I am not able to display the line chart as I am not able to see any lines on chart I am getting type error. I have created React component and inside `componentDidMount()` I have added my line chart code. I think the issue is related to javascript/reactjs and not chartist.js

Code:

```
class Linechart extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){

        const totals = this.props.bowldata.reduce((a, {season, econ})  => {

          if (!a[season]) {
            a[season] = {sum: 0, count: 0};
          }

          if(econ !== null){
            a[season].count++;
            a[season].sum += parseInt(econ);

          }

          return a; 

      }, {});

        const averages = {};

        Object.keys(totals).forEach(key => {   

          averages[key] = totals[key].sum / totals[key].count;

        });

      console.log(averages);

      const series = Object.values(averages);

      const labels = Object.keys(averages);

        const data = {
            series:series,
            labels:labels
        }

        this.linechart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-line-chart', data, options);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 ct-line-chart">
              {this.linechart}
          </div>
        </div>
    )}
}

export default Linechart ;
```

Using `.forEach()` I am trying to create new array of objects with `sum/count` as a `value` and `key` as `year`.

Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The line indicated in the OP is not the line giving the error that is in the console image, which is something like `data.normalized[seriesIndex].forEach is not a function`.

Comment: @RobG How can I find average ? I want `sum/count` as a value and key as `year`.

Comment: @RobG I have edited my question please see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your code like this see if the problem is gone. In [docs](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#chartistline-function-line) it shows `series` should be a multidimensional array.

```
 const data = {
     series:[series],
     labels:labels
 }
```